# Copy temp file before it's deleted

Tags: c#, .net

I had an idea to write some useful code so that the recently downloaded temp files like installation files and other media files can be copied to somewhere safe location before it gets deleted.

```
string dir = "c:\\Users\\neal\\appdata\\Local\\Temp";

string newdir = "D:\\";

var directory = new DirectoryInfo(dir);

var myFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles()
              orderby f.LastAccessTime descending
              select f).First();

var myDir = (from f in directory.GetDirectories()
             orderby f.LastAccessTime descending
             select f).First();

myFile.CopyTo(newdir, true);
```

The above method doesn't actually work. And I'm not sure why. I guess every file may not have access rights (installation files).

Any idea or any other logic out there?

Comment: A few points: Firstly you're not using myDir at all at the moment. Secondly you're using .First() - this will only get you the *first* file in the directory, which is probably the only one you're seeing copied. You probably want more of a recursive approach to this problem.

Comment: How about xcopy called from a .bat script. No need to complicate this.

Comment: Yeah, I'd agree with Chris, unless there's a specific need to do this in code. You could look at robocopy - I've found that does the trick nicely.

Comment: You can avoid myDir for now Because there are other parts where it will used.

Comment: `LastAccessTime` is pretty broken nowadays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I definitely agree that there are already proven solutions to this, however if you wish to implement something in code you should check out the FileSystemWatcher http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

This will notify your program of changes to the directory you are watching so you can take action.

Comment: This is half the solution i was looking for.This is after i find the exact file that has been downloaded recently to temp folder.

Comment: It is not necessary to know the file in advance. If you monitor the temp directory with a filter of "" and handle the events you are interested in, any file Created, Modified, or Deleted will provide the full path in the event that is raised.  So you will automatically get the new file and be able to do something with it with very little code.